# javaScript function doesnt work on my ASP.Net control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a validator control which when I add java Script function to it it doesn't work and a button which I try to change it Text it doesn't work too. the code is Bellow

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function clientValidate(source, args)
        {
            if (parseInt(args.Value) < 10)
            {
                return source.IsValid = false;

            }
            else
            {
                return source.IsValid = true;
            }
        }

        function Alert(ctr)
        {
            alert("Hello");
            ctr.Text = "clicked";
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Value Must not be Below 10" ClientValidationFunction="clientValidate" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" ControlToValidate="txt" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="#FF5050"></asp:CustomValidator>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox> 
            &nbsp; 
            <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="Alert(btn1)" />

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

One thing to say is that the Alert script work but the text of button didn't get changed.

An other thing is the server side event of validator is in separate cs file.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of arguments in the client validation function is incorrect. Correct usage is like this.

```
function clientValidate(source, args)
{
//sender is <span...>err</span> extended properties include controltovalidate
//args is {Value: 123, IsValid: true}
    if (parseInt(args.Value) < 10)
    {
        args.IsValid = false; //not source and no return
        //other logic

    }
    else
    {
        //args.IsValid = true; //redundant. **true** is default value
        //return source.IsValid = true; //see above
        //other logic
    }
}
```

As to `Alert` function. The function is correct and may work. The call is incorrect. Call the function like this.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="Alert(this)" />
```

Note `this` argument in the call.

**Update for comment / extra question**

Custom `Alert`function may take more arguments. Something like this.

```js
function Alert(ctr, msg, evt) {
  if (evt)
    evt.preventDefault();
  switch (ctr.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'input':
    case 'textarea':
      ctr.value = msg;
      break;
    case 'div':
      ctr.innerHTML = msg;
      break;
    default:
      alert(msg);
      break
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="return Alert(this,'clicked',event);" /><br />
<div onclick="Alert(this,'div is clicked')">Click div</div>
```

Comment: thank you bro , the first one work ok. but in the 2nd part . I want to have flexibilty of for example send an other object in the page (forexample asp:textbox control with ID of txt as you see in orginal post) to alert and get it value  and then add it to allert message, is that possible? ==> 

function Alert(ctr)
        {
            alert("Hello" + ctr.Text);
                    }
Or do that ==>

function Alert(ctr)
        {
            alert("Hello");
            ctr.Text = "clicked";
        }

Is it Possible to do ?

Comment: As I understand I can not send asp:Contols to javascript method. so it must be html control. Is'n that?

Comment: Not exactly. `asp:controls` are rendered as HTML elements. Just be careful.

Answer (score 0):

client side does not know about Text and its only accessible on server.
you should use client side attribute instead.

use this:

```
 function Alert(ctr)
    {
        alert("Hello");
        document.getElementById(ctr).value= "clicked";
    }
```

and

```
 <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Button" onClick="Alert('btn1')"/>
```

using of js functions prevents from doing postback on server.

Comment: well 1st: Thank you for reply. 
2nd: I want  to do the javascript effect on ASP.Net controls. 
3rd one is that My main problem(validator) is still exist.